# How to add values from one column based on count of values in another column

Tags: excel

So I have this table:
Column B - hours (integers).
Column C - name (drop-down of values from column R).
Column R - options for the drop-down menu for column C.

What I need:
Column T - for each option (specified in column R) the total amount of hours in column B that are given per name in column C.

Example:
R2 = Josh
In column C I have in 5 cells the name Josh, and next to each one (in column B) I have X hours, so like C2 = Josh, B2 = 10, C5 = Josh, B5 = 3.
I want in T2 to have the value of: 13.

I can count the amount of "Josh"s using COUNTIF(C$2:C$50,R2), but how do I actually count the hours from the corresponding B cells?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: Well that helped exactly, thank you!